# Meteor to not rerender when certain fields change

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor re renders a view when a document changes.

```
Template.story.data = function() {
  var storyID = Session.get('storyID');
  var story = Stories.findOne({
    _id: storyID
  })

  if (!story)
    return;

  return story;
};
```

Here's a template helper for the story template, getting a story from the Stories document.

When fields like `story.title` changes I want the template to rerender. But when fields like `story.viewingusers` change I don't want to rerender the template. Anyway to make that happen?

The specific problem that triggered the question was solved by setting the publish function to not publish those fields. However that solution doesn't work for every usecase and a general solution is needed.

Comment: It's still the correct data right? Is there a reason you don't want the template to render multiple times (beyond optimization?)

Comment: @TomColeman The data is correct, but I have an interface element that shows up as a popover. Every time the element is rerendered the popover is destroyed. That's really annoying.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the [`#constant`](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant) template helper.

What i'd do in your case is wrap the popover markup in a constant block, then update the content in that block manually in the `story.rendered` function.

So something like this:

story.html:

```
<template name="story">
    ...
    {{#constant}}
        <!-- Popover markup here -->
    {{/constant}}
    ...
</template>
```

client.js:

```
Template.story.rendered = function(){
    //Update logic here
}
```

Comment: This is an option, however it ruins the meteor style logic and adds a lot of complexity so I'm hoping for something that more directly addresses the issue.

Comment: Hmm i'm not sure about meteor style logic, but i learnt this technique from the 'parties' example in meteor. You should have a look through that example, it wraps an autorun around the logic so the update logic is invalidated 'in the meteor style' as well.

Comment: Well this forces you to use `Meteor.render` or to build your HTML with dom manipulation. Neither of which are great. I checked out the parties example and this is what they do. This works. but it makes rendering slower, puts templating code into the javascript instead of the templates, and forces you to break up your templates into more pieces. All 3 things add complexity and make things hard to maintain.  But I mean in terms of SO this is an excellent and helpful answer, thanks.

Comment: I disagree regarding the slow rendering, but yes it would break the logical separation in the view code. I don't really think there would be a way to avoid this, unless Meteor built in a standard method to handle this specific use case.

Comment: {{#constant}} has been deprecated and does not exist anymore from what it seems.